# I want to make deep linking in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

As a I am looking for deep linking in flutter web all the answers were of years ago. Is there any modern and easy approach to achieve that. I have a home page in which all the properties were listed, by clicking on the property my url should be domain_name/property_name. I have removed the # by using the seturlpathstrategy(), but not able to provide the custom urls.

Here is my main.dart code which might help.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(const RanHome());
}

class RanHome extends StatelessWidget {
  const RanHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const WelcomeScreen(),
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.id: (context) => const HomeScreen(),
        BuilderBottomBar.id: (context) => const BuilderBottomBar(),
        BuilderLogin.id: (context) => const BuilderLogin(),
        AdviserLogin.id: (context) => const AdviserLogin(),
        AdviserBottomBar.id: (context) => const AdviserBottomBar(),
        BuilderAddProperty.id: (context) => BuilderAddProperty(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try a package like [Go router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) which is

> A declarative routing package for Flutter that uses the Router API to provide a convenient, url-based API for navigating between different screens. You can define URL patterns, navigate using a URL, handle deep links, and a number of other navigation-related scenarios.

Comment: any tutorial based on this.

Comment: I recommend these articles:
- https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade
- https://techblog.geekyants.com/navigation-20-routing-on-flutter-web
- https://medium.flutterdevs.com/navigate-with-gorouter-in-flutter-4a135f813d98
- https://medium.com/@antonio.tioypedro1234/flutter-go-router-the-essential-guide-349ef39ec5b3

Note that some of those articles are using old versions of the package, so I suggest [change log](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/CHANGELOG.md) of the package in case you encountered an error.